# Draw rectangle on uiimage render on GPU

Tags: ios, uiimage, gpu

I need to draw many rectangles on UIImage.
Because there are plenty of rectangle, so i need it render very fast. I think i need to render on GPU.

How can i draw rectangles on UIImage by GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `CALayer` for each rectangle and add them as sublayers of your UIImage. The `CALayer` hierarchy is rendered by the GPU.